# Combine features with nonlinear responses

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I am predicting values with 3 features with responses like this:

1. A close to linear predictor

[image: A close to linear predictor]

2. A feature thats only predictive beyond a threshold

[image: A feature thats only predictive beyond a threshold]

3. A feature with non-linear response like this

[image: A feature with non-linear response]

What machine learning algo would be suitable to combine these features to construct a composite predicative feature? I care more about predicting the extreme values and not so much about values around the mean for my dependent variable. Any suggestion will be appreciated.